# Closest distance from point to surface is normal proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have a point and a surface, the vector for the closest distance between the point and the surface will be normal to the surface:

[image]

Intuitively it makes sense. If we assume the contrary (that the closest distance vector is *not* normal to the surface) then we can minimize the distance by travelling in the direction that makes the distance vector normal. But how would I prove this formally? And does this theorem hold for any type of surface?

Comment: It is normal to the tangent space only, isn't it?

Comment: @user251257 Isn't that the definition of normal?

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), then you're trying to find the minimum of the function
$$
r(X) = \|X-X_0\|
$$
subject to the constraint that $g(X) = 0$, where $g$ implicitly defines the surface. The Lagrange function is
$$
\mathcal{L}(X) = r(X) + \lambda g(X)
$$
Calculating the gradient,
$$
\nabla_{X,\lambda} \mathcal{L} = \left(\frac{X - X_0}{\|X - X_0\|} + \lambda \nabla\,g(X), g(X) \right)
$$

Hence
$$
X - X_0 = -\lambda \|X - X_0\| \nabla g(X).
$$
In other words, the vector $X - X_0$ is collinear to $\nabla g(X)$, which is normal to the surface.